# ASP.NET Core Refresh Token Logic still calling /signin-oidc endpoint

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, refresh-token

Okay, so I am working on creating an OIDC client that will also handle refresh tokens. I have made some progress, but have some questions.

Here is my `ConfigureServices`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
                   
        options.LoginPath = "/Login/Index";
        options.Events.OnValidatePrincipal = async context => await OnValidatePrincipalAsync(context);
     
     
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.Authority = Configuration["auth:oidc:authority"];
        options.ClientId = Configuration["auth:oidc:clientid"];
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["auth:oidc:clientsecret"];
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
        options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "https://contoso.com";
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidIssuer = Configuration["auth:oidc:authority"],
            ValidAudience = Configuration["auth:oidc:clientid"],
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
        };
    });
        
    services.AddAccessTokenManagement();
    services.Configure<OidcOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("oidc"));
}
```

Here is my `OnValidatePrincipalAsync(context)`

```
private async Task OnValidatePrincipalAsync(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
{
    const string AccessTokenName = "access_token";
    const string RefreshTokenName = "refresh_token";
    const string ExpirationTokenName = "expires_at";
    
    if (context.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var exp = context.Properties.GetTokenValue(ExpirationTokenName);
        var expires = DateTime.Parse(exp, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUniversalTime();
        if (expires < DateTime.UtcNow)
        {
            // If we don't have the refresh token, then check if this client has set the
            // "AllowOfflineAccess" property set in Identity Server and if we have requested
            // the "OpenIdConnectScope.OfflineAccess" scope when requesting an access token.
            var refreshToken = context.Properties.GetTokenValue(RefreshTokenName);
            if (refreshToken == null)
            {
                context.RejectPrincipal();
                return;
            }
    
            var cancellationToken = context.HttpContext.RequestAborted;
             
            // Obtain the OpenIdConnect options that have been registered with the
            // "AddOpenIdConnect" call. Make sure we get the same scheme that has
            // been passed to the "AddOpenIdConnect" call.
            //
            // TODO: Cache the token client options
            // The OpenId Connect configuration will not change, unless there has
            // been a change to the client's settings. In that case, it is a good
            // idea not to refresh and make sure the user does re-authenticate.
            var serviceProvider = context.HttpContext.RequestServices;
            var openIdConnectOptions = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsSnapshot<OpenIdConnectOptions>>().Get("OpenIdConnect");
            openIdConnectOptions.Scope.Clear();
            openIdConnectOptions.Scope.Add("email");
            openIdConnectOptions.Scope.Add("profile");
            openIdConnectOptions.Scope.Add("offline_access");
     
            var configuration = openIdConnectOptions.Configuration ?? await openIdConnectOptions.ConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        
            // Set the proper token client options
            var tokenClientOptions = new TokenClientOptions
            {
                Address = configuration.TokenEndpoint,
                ClientId = openIdConnectOptions.ClientId,
                ClientSecret = openIdConnectOptions.ClientSecret,
            };
                    
            var httpClientFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>();
            using var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
                 
            var tokenClient = new TokenClient(httpClient, tokenClientOptions);
            var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(refreshToken, cancellationToken: cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (tokenResponse.IsError)
            {
                context.RejectPrincipal();
                return;
            }
                    
            // Update the tokens
            var expirationValue = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(tokenResponse.ExpiresIn).ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            context.Properties.StoreTokens(new[]
            {
                    new AuthenticationToken { Name = RefreshTokenName, Value = tokenResponse.RefreshToken },
                    new AuthenticationToken { Name = AccessTokenName, Value = tokenResponse.AccessToken },
                    new AuthenticationToken { Name = ExpirationTokenName, Value = expirationValue }
                    });
                  
            // Update the cookie with the new tokens
            context.ShouldRenew = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I've done some experimenting which includes not using the Configuration to get the `OpenIdConnectOptions` in my OnValidatePrincipal and just create a new `OpenIdConnectOptions` object , and I still have not been able to understand my issue.

### Here are my Current Issues

### First Issue

I seem to be able to successfully send a request to the token endpoint after my desired period of time (every 2 minutes and five seconds). I notice that my client application is making a request to the `?authorize` endpoint of my authorization server, even though I don't believe I have it configured to do so in my `OnValidatePrincipalContext` fucntion. I created an all new `OpenIdConnectOptions` object because I thought the current configuration was triggering it.

### First Question

When is this `signin-oidc` request triggered? I think that's what's triggering the request to my authN server's `authorize` endpoint. I should not have to query this endpoint if I'm doing *silent refresh*?

### Second Issue

My authorization server is picking up the `openid` scope when my client makes this request:

```
POST https://<authorization-server>/oauth/oidc/token HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=<refresh-token>&client_id=<client-id>&client_secret=<client-secret>
```

But, in my `OnValidatePrincipalContext` function I explicitly remove the `openid` scope by calling

```
openIdConnectOptions.Scope.Clear();
openIdConnectOptions.Scope.Add("email");
openIdConnectOptions.Scope.Add("profile");
openIdConnectOptions.Scope.Add("offline_access");
```

### Second Question

How do I properly handle the Oidc configuration middleware so that when I go to request a new refresh token the correct request is built and sent to my authN server? Am I doint the wrong kind of authentication scheme (i.e cookie vs bearer)? If I am, how can I tell?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*When is this signin-oidc request triggered?*

Its triggered by the authorization server when the user have successfully authenticated and given consent to the requested scopes. It will ask the browser to post the authorization code to this endpoint. Its typically performed done by using a self-submitting HTML form that will create a post request to this endpoint.

You should always ask for the openid scope, otherwise it won't work.

A picture showing the flow for the endpoint is:

[image]

For the second question one alternative is to take a look at the [IdentityModel.AspNetCore](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.AspNetCore) library. This library can automatically handle the automatic renewal of the access token using the refresh token.

See also [this](https://leastprivilege.com/2019/06/30/another-take-on-access-token-management-in-asp-net-core-and-announcing-identitymodel-aspnetcore/) blog post

Comment: this kind of work-around should be posted as comment only, unless you could explain something wrong with the OP's original issue and instead of trying to solve it, we should switch to another alternative (or work-around) solution.

Comment: I clarified my answer :-)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But, is it possible to NOT trigger the `/signin-oidc` if all I want the client to do is ask for a new access token? 

I guess I should say that I have some logic to just refresh the page on my secure page, which will trigger the `OnPrincipalValidated` function, which will then renew my access token. Is that my issue? I don't want the `signin-oidc` to happen at all since the user has already authorized the application, and all I am doing is requesting a new access token with the refresh token.

Comment: /signin-oidc should only be called once when the user initially logs in.   For getting new tokens you call the token endpoint, see https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/token.html

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. But, my client seems to be reissuing the /authorize request even though the user is logged in. That's my confusion. I see a request to my OAuth server using the `grant_type=refresh_token`. It fails, but right after, I see another request from my client to the `authorize` endpoint

Comment: Are you sure you send that request to the correct endpoint? Are you sure you do ask for a new request token slightly before the access token expires? are you sure refresh tokens are even supported or enabled? Perhaps the refresh token has expired?

Comment: I would look at the raw HTTP traffic in Fiddler to explore the requests made to your identity provider and explore what happens and what the tokens contains